# What is the saying to express a certain situation? It is like, you will find nails everywhere when you have got a hammer

Tags: expressions, popular-refrains

I am looking for a saying to express a situation that one is apt to apply anything instantly when it is at hand. I do not remember the saying. It seems to be that 'you will find nails everywhere when you have got a hammer'. I know it was used in some article of the US. What is the original saying?

For the saying, I think it implies that it is always easy for anyone to find an excuse for doing something. Does it sometimes mean that?

Comment: Entering "you will find nails everywhere when you have got a hammer" into Google, Bing, Altavista, Lycos, Yahoo, and probably others, reliably gets you [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) as the top result, [and this dictionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail) not much further down. You could also have searched this very site for ["nails hammer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=nails+hammer).

Comment: @RegDwigнt I guess he didn't have a search box. "If you don't have a hammer, there could be nails everywhere and you would not see them." Ouch! Careful walking...

Answer (score 2):

> "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

[Source](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail)

I think you are somewhat correct. It does kind of mean that people will find to do something, *in a specific manner* when their knowledge or resources are limited. They are inclined to believe that their method is correct and the best possible one.